# How to correctly configure OSGeo4W64 for Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: java, osgeo4w, configuration

I have successfully installed [OSGeo4W64](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe) on numerous new systems (actually EC2 instances) and had no issues.  But I've run into an issue with it on a Windows 7 workstation that has  a lot of JREs on it.  Because of that, I set my paths from a batch to whatever JRE I need to use. But I can't get any of 64-bit versions to work:a `ogrinfo --help` throws the missing jvm.dll machine error message.

Which JRE should I be using and how should the pathing for the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables be set?

[image]

Update:

1. Removed all JREs/SDKs.
2. Installed JRE 1.7 (jre1.7.0_67) - 64 bit.
3. Set the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables.
4. Started ogrinfo.exe and received a different error:

[image]

Comment: Oh that seems to be the end of QGIS for me. Use the installer and it stops working forever. Yay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue with OSGeo4W64 was due to the fact that I did an advanced install (although I don't recall what I chose...it was probably everything).

After purging every thing Java from the system and reinstalling the jre1.7.0_67, I still received more errors.  Then I removed OSGeo4W64 and reinstalled with the Express Desktop Install:

[image]

Then:
[image]

Then proceed as normal through the install wizard.

After that, I still received this error message for `ogrinfo.exe` and `ogr2ogr.exe`:
[image]

I grabbed  the DLL from the QGIS\bin directory (which was already installed) and put it in `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin` and I was able to run `ogrinfo.exe` and `ogr2ogr.exe` with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same as 1-st message when I update from 1.11.2 to 1.11.3 by 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\setup.bat'. As usual I use extended mode and choose 'Set JRE environment' as additional option to automaticly selected "Install" options. I think it's not bad to have java as an option with gdal/ogr.But it was a bad idea.

After install I can't work because of the error (jvm.dll).
I trace ini bat files and find that java.bat set JAVA-environmet to OSGeo root folder, where this OSGeo pack and other, as I have several of them in other folders, have no any jvm.dll. I have JRE in other folder, but I am sure it's was not installed by OSGeo pack install.

So, I run setup once more and select to uninstall 'Java env...'. After install I have several iterations of install OSGeo with other 'missing *.dll', same as You show.

I had fixed my copy of OSGeo4W64 by choosing main option 'Reinstall' in 'All' sections. After reinstall I have no problems with gdal/ogr command line utils.

Comment: also had the same problem after adding java to my osgeo4w installation. Reinstall in the advanced section and it now all works.